# Accessing values from a Map<string, List<string>>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm struggling to get the `string` values from a `Map<string, List<string>>` object. The object contains this information:

```
{"thisKeyName": [Array]}
```

The `[Array]` contains something like this:

`["Contact 1", "Contact 2", "Contact 3"]`

I'm able to access the `[Array]` values of the object like this:

```
let contactCards = currentUser.contacts; // <- this is the Map object
const ids = [];

contactCards.forEach(folder => {
  folder.forEach(contact => {
    ids.push(contacts);
  });
});
```

However, I want to access the `"ThisKeyName"` value to put it on another array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why doesn't `contactCards.get("ThisKeyName")` work here?

Comment: @VLAZ Because ```ThisKeyName``` is a randomly generated id I generated using uuid, so I don't know the concrete name of ```ThisKeyName``` unless I print ```contactCards``` on the console

Comment: Is `ThisKeyName` a variable? so what is the problem with `contactCards.get(ThisKeyName)`

Comment: pls provide a reproducable example

Comment: @DanielCorona then you really need to specify the exact problem in your question. Right now you're asking how to access a map value by its key. The answer will be to use `get`. If you *don't* want to do that, then explain what you do or don't have and what exactly are you looking for. I'm currently unsure whether `"ThisKeyName"` is actually a value you *have* or not. And if you do in what form. And if you don't, then how exactly are you supposed to find what you're looking for.